# How to change AutoCompleteTextView border color of default theme in android?

Tags: android, border, autocompletetextview

I am using `AutoCompleteTextView` in my android application. I am using `Theme.Light` as my default theme for my application.

Here is how my `AutoCompleteTextView` look like
[image]

Now, I want to change the BLUE color border of that `AutoCompleteTextView` to some other color  ,for different selection, keeping the border style as it as. I dont want full border. How to do that?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485595/change-edittext-border-color

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this..

see http://www.androidworks.com/changing-the-android-edittext-ui-widget for details

For other theme implementation go for this way
 In your manifest in application

```
    android:theme="@style/firsttheme"
```

IN res/values you can define theme.xml

```
<resources> 
    <style name="firsttheme" parent="@android:style/Theme" > 
       <item name="android:_DEFAULT_BASE_COLOR_1">#XXXXXX</item>
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        ... . 
    </style>
</resources>
```

For more info [theme](http://janrain.com/blog/introduction-to-android-theme-customization/)

Comment: @Janmejoy.. Can you please tell me how to change the above blue color to red

Comment: @TaruniNeema do you want to change the theme or only the border

Comment: @TaruniNeema  try this link for theme..http://janrain.com/blog/introduction-to-android-theme-customization/

Comment: I want to change that `BLUE` color border to some other color. Thats it. I dont want complete 4 sided border. I want the same style as it is in the above figure.

Comment: Ya.. It means that I need to create a 9 patch image of my own color isn't?

Comment: yep...if you take my advice then i will tell you that change the theme with the colors every thing will be all-right

Comment: let me know if you will get the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com) to tint it. It generates the 9-patchs and the styles.