# Change Border Color of Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I tried making a 9 patch image and setting that as background as many solutions suggest but that didn't change the border color when the edittext is selected. In fact, there is no border now, just the image of the edittext. How can I simply change the border color of it? To be for example blue instead of yellow. 
[image]

Comment: Refer to this http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/changing-background-color-and-border-color-of-an-edittext-widget-using-state-list-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a `selector` when the `Edittext` is `focused` or `selected` the image changes of the `Edittext`.

**sample:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/edittext_pressed"/> //9patch for pressed 
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_focused"/> //9patch for focused
    <item 
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/edittext_normal"/> //9patch for normal
</selector>
```

This selector is then added in the background of the `Edittext`.

Comment: Tried it and says Rendering Problems NOTE: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts. <selector> does not set the required layout_width attribute:..... what is this? =/

Comment: @darkchampionz put it in the drawable folder not in the layout folder

Comment: I go in res -> drawable-xhdpi and create the xml there. but then it is placed under layout folder automatically D:

Comment: @darkchampionz just try to put it in the drawable just drawable np dpi extension

Comment: Copy and pasted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485595/change-edittext-border-color??

Comment: thanks for your help. looks like this point is only missing. however I have no drawable folder. source -> main -> res then there are only drawables dpi folders =/

Comment: @darkchampionz make sure that you create xml first; right click drawable-xhdpi --> new --> android xml --> Resource type drawable

Comment: under xml, it gives me only the options of layout xml file and values xml file

Comment: @darkchampionz that is weird... try to create a new folder named drawable in the res folder.

Comment: @darkchampionz create one xml file, it's ok if it is of type layout. After creating, open it and replace everything with the above code. Make sure that xml file is under drawable.

Comment: ok took some time to figure it out, had to go new -> file -> drawable resource file (f*k androidstudio). thanks for your help and patience. I will continue to check if rest works too

Answer (score 0):

Use the below step to change the border color.

- editText.Background.SetColorFilter(Color.Red);